# Array of TButtons - how to control them

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, pascal

I am currently making "noughts and crosses" as homework. I generated a 10x10 array of `TButton` objects, but I don't know how they are called and how to control them:

```
Form1: TForm1;
  pole: array[1 .. 10, 1 .. 10] of TButton;
  h:TButton;

for i:=1 to 10 do
  for j:=1 to 10 do
  begin
    h:=TButton.Create(Self);
    h.Parent:=Self;
    h.Width:=50;
    h.Height:=50;
    h.Left:=((i+1)*50)-100;
    h.top:=((j+1)*50)-100;
    h.OnClick := hClick;
  end;
```

Are my buttons even in that array? I must say I am confused a bit here.

Comment: Is that how your code is really indented? It's very hard to read. One can't help imagine that you might have missed important code in this apparently hurried pasting exercise.

Answer (score 8):

You have to assign every newly created button object to appropriate array entry.

Another important thing - inside common event handler you probably want to determine what button is pressed. Possible way - use object field Tag

```
for i:=1 to 10 do
  for j:=1 to 10 do  begin
   h:=TButton.Create(Self);
   pole[i, j] := h;
   ... 
   h.OnClick := hClick;
   h.Tag := 10 * i + j; //store both row and column
end;


procedure ...hClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j: integer;
begin
   i := (Sender as TButton).Tag div 10;  // extract row and column
   j := (Sender as TButton).Tag mod 10; 
   ...
end;
```

Comment: Better way, subclass the button type and add fields to hold row and column

Comment: @David Seems overkill for the beginner

Answer (score 2):

At the end of for-loop add

```
pole[i][j] := h;
```

Because every iteration you just overwrite variable 'h' and nothing gets added into array.